# Do I need to create a Promise object for a failed async fetch?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am using `async await` to call `fetch`, but it's not clear to me how to reject the result, and what to return, if the fetch fails. 
(for example, because the url is incorrect).

```
async loadJSON(url) {
  try {
      let res = await fetch(url)
      return res.json()
  } 
  catch (err) {
      // do I need to create a new promise here and reject it?
      // or can I just return false?
      return // erm...
  }
}

// calling the function, preferably without using try catch here
let result = await loadJSON("bla.php")
```

EDIT

I would like all my fetch and error handling code to be inside `loadJSON`, so I don't need to sprinkle `try catch` everywhere around my app.

Comment: i'm guessing since its an async method already, it will resolve with what you return.

Comment: to reject it, just throw.

Comment: ... or remove the `try`/`catch` block entirely.

Comment: To add to @DanielA.White's comment, it is better to let the exception be thrown. You could catch it here and return false but you should let the error be passed up the chain.

Comment: So the `try catch` should be around `let result = await loadJSON()` ? I was trying to avoid that, by just having all the data loading code in one function.

Comment: If you have nothing else to do in the `catch()` block, then just remove it.  Because it's an `async` function, it will automatically catch that and return a rejected promise for you.  If you have something else to do in the `catch()` block and want it to still return a rejected promise, then just `throw err` at the end of the `catch()` block.  The caller can then use `.then()` and `.catch()` to delineate success and failure.

Comment: It all depends on what your program is planning to do when it fails. Do you want loadJSON to be responsible for providing a default value if it fails? Your question does not make it clear because in the sample code you're not sure what to return if it fails (I assume that's what `erm...` means). It seems to me that loadJSON is a general function that shouldn't know what to do if it fails but the function calling it or even further up does know.

Comment: "*I would like all my fetch and error handling code to be inside `loadJSON`*" - but what would `loadJSON` return in case of an errror? An empty object? And then the calling code would need to *handle* that?

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this:

```
function loadJson(url) {
  return fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => ({ isSuccess: true, data }))
  .catch(error => ({ isSuccess: false, error }))
}
```

And then:

```
let result = await loadJson("bla.php")
```

And then:

```
if (result.isSuccess) {
  // result.data
} else {
  // result.error 
}
```

Or:

```
return result.isSuccess ? result.data : result.error
```